# Google Map inside siding panel - grey squares

Tags: jquery, google-maps

thanks for taking the time to check my question.

Here it is -- I saw a Google Maps implementation that I am trying to replicate on a client site, but I am having difficulties.

Here is the effect I am trying to recreate - http://www.franckmaurin.com/.  When you click "Get in Touch" a Google Map expands from the top of the page, pushing the content down.

So here is how I am trying it --

```
<body>
<div id="map-container">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<p id="open-map">Open The Map</a>

.. rest of content

</body>
```

And then my CSS

```
#map_canvas {
height:350px;
width:100%;
}

#map-container {
height:0px;
}
```

..and then the JS

```
$('.open-map').click(function() {
  $('#map-container').css("height",350);
});
```

..this is a stripped down version obviously. I want to animate the dropdown too.. but I keep getting an incomplete map that looks like this http://d.pr/rNnr.  Incomplete with lots of grey.  I have tried different approaches to opening and closing (including setting {height:350px; display:none} on the container but this problem is always there.  If I don't hide the map container there is no problem with the map.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you should set `#map-container` css style,

```
#map-container {
  float:left;
  height:350px;
  width:960px;//or other width you need
  display:none;
}
```

then use jquery to control   `#map-container` `slideUp` and `slideDown`

Comment: Thanks!  But I found another solution... 

I set map-container to height:350px and used position:absolute top:-350px.  So at that point the map is actually fully rendered but sitting in a big div off the top of the screen.  (I really think the problem is caused by having the map render inside a "closed"/hidden div).  

Then I set body to absolute also, and used jquery to toggle animate the <body> to top:350px to open the panel and top:0px to close.

Comment: @K.K. Smith, so can u parse more code? such as `http://jsfiddle.net/` I would like to help u more.